# In which context can I use "gea"?

Tags: word-usage, nouns

[Word-Building with Esperanto Affixes](http://literaturo.org/HARLOW-Don/Esperanto/affixes.html) says that *gea* means *male+female*, and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gea#Esperanto) says it means *both sexes, mixed*.

Can I use it to mean *a person having the reproductive organs of both genders*, or does it have a completely different meaning and I should not use for such meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you could use it to describe a single person having mixed gender, I think that would be a pretty unusual usage and it would be more common to describe a mixed group of people or a location that is suitable for any gender. Here are some examples from *Monato*:

> Krom la tradiciaj ekleziaj lernejoj unuseksaj, estis fonditaj en la du landpartoj de la irlanda insulo pluraj nesektecaj aŭ interkonfesiaj **geaj** lernejoj.

Here *gea lernejo* is used to describe a school that both boys and girls can attend.

> Tial fine oni iom kompromisis: samseksaj paroj sub la nova leĝo estos ĉiurilate egalaj al **geaj paroj**, kun la escepto, ke gejaj kaj lesbaj paroj rajtos leĝe adopti infanojn nur el Nederlando mem.

Here *gea paro* describes a couple that has both a man and a woman. (This sounds confusingly similar to *geja paro* which is used in the same sentence!)

[PMEG says](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/prefiksoj/ge.html#i-lp4) that in practice this word isn’t used very often outside of being a prefix.

To specify having both sexes it may be better to use the word *ambaŭseksa* which appears in PIV as follows:

> **ambaŭseksa, duseksa**. Havanta ambaŭ seksojn: *helikoj estas ambaŭseksaj; duseksa floro*. Sin. hermafrodita.

Comment: Could not _gea paro_ be written as _geparo_?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes, I don’t see why not. However it only appears once in Tekstaro and that is just as an example of a creative word, so maybe it isn’t very common. But of course it is completely understandable and Esperanto is more open to making up words on the spot so that doesn’t mean it’s a bad word.

Comment: Actually, that is like writing _suna sistemo_ instead of _sunsistemo_. I have always thought that using _sunsistemo_ would be more Esperantisque than using _suna sistemo_, but indeed both are correct.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Wouldn't that more likely mean something more like "a member of a group of paroj kaj parinoj" – in other words, not much?